# Java JAXB 2.0 Version

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

We just upgraded to Java 8 and I'm seeing the following error in our logs. My lead tells me I need to re-compile with an older version of JAXB, can anyone tell me where I can go to download JAXB 2.0 ? Or suggest another solution to this error?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType.value()Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/AccessType;
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getAccessType(ClassInfoImpl.java:339)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:49)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:41)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:51)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:201)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:55)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:131)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:335)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:431)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:394)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader$3.run(MetroConfigLoader.java:259)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader$3.run(MetroConfigLoader.java:256)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.createJAXBContext(MetroConfigLoader.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.loadMetroConfig(MetroConfigLoader.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.init(MetroConfigLoader.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.<init>(MetroConfigLoader.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:295)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:814)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:803)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
```

Comment: which sort of build system are you using? maven? gradle? ant? some more information would go a long way to us helping you

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using maven or gradle just set the appropriate version, it will be downloaded from maven central repository. Otherwise you can manually download it and add it to classpath. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.0